# Match link text and querystring of href PHP

Tags: php, string, echo, href

I am using PHP.

I need to take the text inside the `a` tag and add it to the querystring of the `href` attribute.

Example:

```
<a href="page.php">sometext</a>
```

becomes:

```
<a href="page.php?q=sometext">sometext</a>
```

So I just links any word to page.php, but when a user clicks on it it goes "page.php?q=sometext", or the actual link changes from "page.php" to "page.php?q=sometext".

If possible, please make an example using [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net) or [phpfiddle.org](http://phpfiddle.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the client side with jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('a').each(function(index, element){
            href = $(element).attr('href');
            $(element).attr('href', href + "?q=" + $(element).text());
        });
    });
</script>
```

an example: https://jsfiddle.net/jgj7k19o/

Comment: Thanks, but couldn't get it to work, can you have a working example using jsfiddle.net or phpfiddle.org

Comment: it works great, however it turns all the links in the page and add ?q=.  I need it only to add that to links named "page.php", and not any other links

Comment: look at this example that matches the href attribute of anchor to be "page.php"  https://jsfiddle.net/yvhv007y/

Comment: Thanks a lot..  I have another question: can I make it echo 3 values in 3 places in the new url respectively (like verses)? Example: <a href="page.php">Mt 5: 2</a> becomes <a href="page.php?book=Mt&chapter=5&vmin=2">Mt 5: 2</a>

Comment: I think would be better do this in server side, but if you really need to do it in the client take a look at this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3jcpob6/)

Comment: server side how?  This is my final code after some edits, can you check it and answer there with a suggestion for server-side code, or an edit to the existing one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560121/arabic-encoding-for-matched-texted-with-querystring

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use JavaScript to do that?

Using jQuery -

```
$(function (){
    $("a[href='page.php']").attr("href","page.php?q=query");
})
```

Here is the JSfiddle example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cq5Lfhjk/)

Comment: Thanks.. can you have a working example using jsfiddle.net or phpfiddle.org

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter; if you want to display the string in the url, you have to use routes. After you passed the data from your controller into your view using foreach, in your view will look like this one.

Example from my previous project

**View**

```
<?php foreach($var as $row){?>
 <a href="<?= base_url().'events/edit_events/'.$row->event_name?>"Edit
<?php }?>
```

**Routes**

```
$route['events/edit_events/(:any)'] = 'events/edit_events/$1';
```

In my routes :any meaning it can be an id,name etc.

In here, I used a dropdown list. Assuming that you have 3 data's in your event table. When I select "Edit" in my First Event,then I pass it you my routes. So your url will now become localhost/project/events/edit_events/event1.

Answer (score -1):

The only way with exclusively PHP is to write both the inner HTML and the `href` attribute with PHP.

Example:

```
echo '<a href="foo.php?' . $bar .'">' . $bar .' .</a>';
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be exclusively PHP, just anything that works within..  The tag is always "<a href="page.php">sometext</a> ".  What is needed is something to echo (or match) whatever between > < and add it after ?q=

Comment: @Mike sorry, it wasn't clear from your question that this needed to be variable based not on server side but client side information outside the headers. That is not possible with PHP or any server side language, and the question was phrases in a way that made it seem as though PHP were required