# Arabic encoding for matched texted with querystring

Tags: php, jquery, match, href

I am using a jQuery to match text between `> <` and changing it as follows, from this:

```
<a href="page.php">Mt 5: 2</a><br>
<a href="page.php">Nd 14: 25</a
```

To this:

```
<a href="page.php?book=80&chapter=5&vmin=2">Mt 5: 2</a>
<a href="page.php?book=95&chapter=15&vmin=25">Nd 14: 25</a>
```

The code is:

```
var myarray = { 'Mt': 80, 'Lu': 81, 'Rv': 92, 'Nd': 95 }; // you can add more values
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a[href='page.php']").each(function(index, element){
    href = $(element).attr('href'); // get the href
    text = $(element).text().split(' '); // get the text and split it with space
    $(element).attr('href', href + "?book=" + $.trim(myarray[text[0]]) + "&chapter=" + $.trim(text[1].slice(0, -1)) + "&vmin=" + $.trim(text[2])); //create desired href and replace it with older-one
  });
});
```

However, when I try Arabic letters instead, it doesn't work. Like: `<a href="page.php">كم 5: 2</a>` and `var myarray = {'كم':80`

I tried changing the charset to "windows-1256" or "utf-8" in the php file meta tag or script tag, but still it doesn't read the Arabic and just shows the link as follows `<a href="page.php?book=&chapter=5&vmin=2">Mt 5: 2</a>` as if there is nothing to put after `book=`.

Comment: `var myarray = {'كم':80` isn't valid syntax as the quotes are wrong. Presumably you want this instead: `var myarray = {'80': 'كم'}`. Although you should note that 'myarray' is badly named, as it's an object. Using `encodeUriComponent()` would probably help too

Comment: Thanks for replying.  No, `var myarray = {'كم':80` is right, but Arabic changes the layout of the quotes (in view only, not in code).  As for `encodeUriComponent()`, could you make a code snippet here or using jsfiddle as an example?

Comment: Sure, here's the documentation for it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent